# US Quarter Dollar Coins of different states (4 sets)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, money

I have been collecting US quarter dollar coins for different states and I have 4 sets of these coins. Can I take them along with me when travelling back to India. Can I take them in my carry on luggage or should I keep them in the check-in baggage. Please suggest.

Comment: What exactly is your concern?  The monetary value is about $100

Comment: As far as the US is concerned; they're not different than any other coins in circulation here.  As long as you're not transporting thousands of dollars of currency you can take them out of the US however you want.

Comment: If nothing else, I'd put them in my checked luggage so I didn't have to lug around the extra weight.  Two hundred quarters—i.e., four sets of 50—weigh about 1.1 kg.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Complete set is times 2.  You have to consider that there are 2 minting of the same coin (Denver and Phila)

Comment: @Karlson:  Fair point — but that just makes the weight even greater.

Comment: I wanted to know whether it is legal to take out 200 coins. I have them wrapped in a cotton bag. I am planning to buy a book like thingy which allows us to keep the coins, similar to stamp collection.

Comment: @Soumya Legal from who's perspective and in what way? India, US, the airline?  This is basically currency that you're bringing, so same rules apply.

Comment: @Karlson Legal in a sense like carrying 200 quarter dollar coins from US to India. Airlines should not have any issues related to this. But thank you for the clarifications, as this is also basically currency, it should not be an issue. Now if only I could mark comment as an answer. If you respond as an answer, then I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that's 1134 g, which is 2.5 lbs.  US "silver" coins are worth $20 per pound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no legal limit to the amount of money you can bring out of the US. However, you do need to fill out forms if you want to bring out more than $10,000. The value of your collection, assuming you have 4 complete sets (including the Denver and Philadelphia mints as @Karlson mentioned) is $100, well below the limit.

From [U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195/):

> There is no limit on the amount of money that can be taken out of or
>   brought into the United States. However, if a person or persons
>   traveling together and filing a joint declaration (CBP Form 6059-B)
>   have $10,000 or more in currency or negotiable monetary instruments,
>   they must fill out a "Report of International Transportation of
>   Currency and Monetary Instruments" FinCEN 105 (former CF 4790).

Considering this collection is probably more valuable to you personally than $100, I would recommend taking it as carry-on. It is a lot of weight, however, I imagine replacing the collection if your checked bag is lost would be very difficult.

There is no legal limit to the amount of money you can bring into India. However, you do need to fill out forms if you want to bring in more than $5,000 USD or more than $10,000 USD, depending on the composition of the money assets. Your $100 value collection falls well below this limit.

From [Mumbai Airport Customs](http://customsmumbaiairport.gov.in/Hindi/Content.aspx?LinkID=70):

> Any person can bring into India from any place outside India foreign
>   exchange without any value limit. However, a declaration to the
>   Customs authorities shall be made in the prescribed Currency
>   Declaration Form (CDF) in the following cases:- (a) Where the
>   aggregate value of foreign currency notes exceeds US$ 5000/- or
>   equivalent; or
>
> (b) Where the aggregate value of foreign exchange in the form of
>   currency notes, bank notes or traveller’s cheques exceeds US$ 10,000/-
>   or its equivalent.

Comment: Now that's a complete information from all angle. Thanks.